# ValueError: Too many values to unpack in recursive graph search

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Problem

As part of a uni assignment im building a program to find a shortest path from one road to another. I'm using an algorithm called recursive best-first search to do so, and im getting the ValueError as the recursion unwinds and tries to unpack the solution (Stored as a list of nodes, from goal node to root node). The recursive call is stored in the variables 'result' and 'best.f' as seen in the second last line in the search algorithm.

## Code

Included below is the main algorithm and the relevant (but not all) methods

#### Search algorithm: [(Based on this pseudocode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxXQU.jpg)

```
def find_path_from_to(problem):
    return RBFS_Road(problem,Node(problem.start,None,None,0,problem),math.inf)

def RBFS_Road(problem,node,f_limit):
    if problem.goaltest(node): return solution(node)
    successors = []
    for action in problem.actions(node):
        successors.append(Node(action.current_pos,node, 
        [node.current_pos,action],node.g+1,problem))
    if not successors: return "failure",math.inf
    for s in successors:
        s.f = max(s.g+s.h,node.f)
    while True:
        best = min_node(successors)
        if best.f > f_limit: return "failure",best.f
        alternative = alt(successors)
        result,best.f = RBFS_Road(problem,best,min(f_limit,alternative))
        if result != "failure": return result
```

#### The function that returns the solution list and the Node and Problem class

```
def solution(node):
    solution_list = [node.current_pos]
    current_node = node
    while current_node.parent is not None:
        solution_list.append(current_node.parent.current_pos)
        current_node = current_node.parent
    return [solution_list,None]
```

|

```
class Problem():
    def __init__(self,start,goal,city_data):
        self.start = start
        self.goal = goal
        self.city_data = city_data

    def goaltest(self,node):
        return node.current_pos.split(' ',1)[0] == self.goal.split(' ',1)[0]
    def actions(self,node):
        return find_neighbors(node,self.city_data)

class Node():
    def __init__(self,current_pos,parent,action,steps,problem):
        self.current_pos  = current_pos
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
        self.problem = problem
        self.g = steps
        self.h = h_heu(self,self.problem.city_data)
        self.f = self.g + self.h
```

## What i've tried

The recursive call is assigned to 2 variables, the first will end up a list and the second helps redirect the search when the algorithm decides to backtrack. The second variable 'best.f' is set to 'None' when the solution is found because we dont need it anymore. So naturally i set the solution list to return [a list,None], but still i get the unpack error.

I then tried to print out the result of the recursive call along with the length of the output by inserting the line with the recursive call in a print statement above the original recursive call:

```
print(RBFS_Road(args),len(RBFS_Road(args))
```

(replaced actual arguments with 'args' for readability)

And it outputs the following:

```
('failure', 4.0) 2
('failure', 4.0) 2
('failure', 4.0) 2
[['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37'], None] 2
('failure', 4.0) 2
('failure', 4.0) 2
[['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37'], None] 2
['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37'] 4
('failure', 4.0) 2
('failure', 4.0) 2
[['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37'], None] 2
```

And the stacktrace, after comment:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RouteFinding_New.py", line 120, in <module>
    main(str(sys.argv[1]),str(sys.argv[2]),str(sys.argv[3]))
  File "RouteFinding_New.py", line 117, in main
    solution = find_path_from_to(problem)
  File "RouteFinding_New.py", line 37, in find_path_from_to
    return 
RBFS_Road(problem,Node(problem.start,None,None,0,problem),math.inf)
  File "RouteFinding_New.py", line 51, in RBFS_Road
  print(RBFS_Road(problem,best,min(f_limit,alternative)),len(RBFS_Road(problem,best,min(f_limit,alternative))))
File "RouteFinding_New.py", line 52, in RBFS_Road
result,best.f = RBFS_Road(problem,best,min(f_limit,alternative))
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I think the culprit is the line that has length 4 since it doesnt have None in it. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the None disappears.

## The question

Why does my program give me the 'Too many values to unpack error' and what can i do to solve it. The problem is probaly solved if i could figure out why the 'None' disappears from the solution list (in the 'What ive tried' section)

#### Note:

I tried to include only the relevant parts of the problem because its already really long, so if you want to know anything more feel free to add a comment. Thanks in advance for anyone that tries to help

Comment: When stripping down code that's too long to post, you need to make sure what's left is *runnable* and *reproduces the error* when you run it. This commonly involves some degree of editing, or even building a new example snippet from scratch. Also, we need to see the error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: When unpacking you unpack `[['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37'], None]` - the offending thing `['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37']` lacks a `[...]` around it and the `None` - you probably unpack like a,b = ... - if you feed it `*['street_3 45', 'avenue_0 23', 'avenue_0 21', 'street_1 37']` it cant unpack as it has 4 instead of 2 elements of `[ [....], None]` - and what @user2357112 said - without runnable code its hard to debug your error.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112, i added the stacktrace under the output section.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply  @Patrick Artner. Yes, im sure its that part of the program that is giving me a headache, but im having a hard time figuring out why that particular list has its None and [...] removed. As for runnable code, i have a long data set as .txt, a seperate program to parse that file, and the program here that the snippets are from totals 120 lines. Is there any "easy" way i could let you use those components?

Comment: At least line `if result != "failure": return result` looks wrong since it returns only single variable instead of a list or tuple with two elements. Maybe the code should throw an exception if there is some sort of failure.

Comment: @ThomasB. is this fixed?